# How to draw heart shape using Maple

Tags: maple

I'm drawing a heart shape using Maple, but the heart-shaped curve is broken. Please hint to me how to draw it correctly.

[image]

Comment: $+^++^++^++^++$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `numpoints=8000`, not `numpoint=8000`.  :)

Another option (instead of `numpoints`) is to use `grid`.

You may also want to look at plotting [Cardioids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid).

Answer (score 1):

The equation  a limaçon in polar coordinates has the form $$r=a+b\cos(\theta)$$[image]

[see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on)

Answer (score 0):

Use this 2 equation and plot them:

x(t) = 4.5 sin t − sin 3t + 0.8 sin 15.25t,

y(t) = 4 cos t − 1.5 cos 2t − 0.6 cos 3t − 0.3 cos 4t + 0.8 cos 15.25t